# route in rails does not find a query string for the main index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I want to create a URL to the index with a query string, but I do not manage to do it. Need some help, thanks!

If I use the helper method to create URL:

```
link_to 'Movie Title', movie_path(:sort_by=>'title')
```

I get a routing error:

```
"No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies", :sort_by=>:title}"
```

However it works when I use it with a *:id*, but a get a URL to movies/:id/sort_by=title and I do not want that:

```
link_to 'Movie Title', movie_path(1,:sort_by=>'title')
```

My rake routes outpus is :

```
    movies GET    /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movies"}
           POST   /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movies"}
 new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movies"}
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
     movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movies"}
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movies"}
```

Answer (score 6):

`movie_path` is for one movie - if you want a list you should user `movies_path`

Have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

*edit: added link*

Comment: could you accecpt the answer if it works? glad i could help :)

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could accept the answer if it worked. (Just click on the tick beside of the answer)

Comment: how does my routes know the difference between `movie` and `movies`?  I had the same issue and don't understand how this fixes it.

Comment: Have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources. This might help you understand the different between singular resources and normal ones. Singular resources are used if you want the user of the website always to access the same element - normal ("plural") resouces if the user should be able to choose which element to access.